# not able to insert data in sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

hi am new to android and am creating an alarm i am not able to insert hour and minute in data base here the below is my all source code any one please help me to solve this problem . while running the program i am getting Nullpointer exception at insert method.

```
public  void setListAdapter(SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter) {
    String[] alarm = new String[] { "select*from " + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME };
    return ;
}

private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {

    intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReciever.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1,
            intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent);
    textAlarmPrompt.setText("\n\n***\n" + "Alarm is set@ "
            + targetCal.getTime() + "\n" + "Repeat every 5 minutes\n"
            + "***\n");
    int hour = targetCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = targetCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    Log.d(TAG, "value" + hour + minute);

    String h = Integer.toString(hour);
    String m = Integer.toString(minute);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("hour", h);
    values.put("minute", m);
    insertalarmclock(h, m);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    // private void clearAll() {
    // SQLiteDatabase mDB = null;
    // mDB.delete(MyDatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    //
    // }
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST" + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME + ""
            + KEY_ID + "INTEGER AUTOINCRREMENT ," + KEY_ALARM_HOUR
            + "TIME," + KEY_ALARM_MINUTE + "TIME,)");
}

public long insertalarmclock(String h, String m) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("hour", h);
    values.put("minute", m);
    String val = (String) values.get(h);
    Log.d(TAG, "value" + val + h + m);

    return mDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, null, values);

}

private SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
    return null;
}
```

and my error is
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at insertalarmclock(AlarmActivity.java:435)
        at setAlarm(AlarmActivity.java:412)

Comment: That's a big wall of code. Edit your question, and cut it down to the smallest program that illustrates your problem. Include any error messages you get.

Comment: i have edited the code please check it

Comment: setAlarm(calSet); just change setAlarm(Calendar.getInstance()); check whther working or not

Comment: it is throwing the same error?

Answer (score 0):

In `insertalarmclock()`, call `insert()` on the `db` you init with `getWritableDatabase()`, not `mDb` that's likely `null`.